# Using Adobe Brackets to edit

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-brackets

Is it possible to preview edit a live website such as updates using Brackets? I know there is the project settings field where it is used for local hosted filed but what if I entered a website in general. I've tried this and when previewing, the website showed up but nothing changed in the brackets code. Could this act as the inspect element for the website?

I would really like to know how if this is even possible.

Thank you so much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

Live Preview works by serving your current project via a local server that connects Google Chrome via its remote debugging protocol. This implies that your project has to be local.